# Does a callback execute when other function is running?

Tags: python, class, callback

I have a conceptual doubt.

If I pass a class method as a callback function (to another program running on other thread) and I get struck in some other class method (not the callback method) eg `while(True)`.
Will the `callback` **ever** *execute*?

```
class Bicycle(object):
   __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
       self.f = 0

   def callback(self, push_force):
       #Go ahead
       self.f = push_force
   def balance(self):
       while True:
           # Balance the Bicycle

def main():
    B1 = Bicycle("Red")
    external(callback=B1.callback)
    while True:
        B1.balance()
```

Comment: The callback executes only if your external function decides so... We'd need a [mcve].

Comment: Your question is not clear at all... In any case, if the callback is passed to an other thread then, yes it can execute while your `balance` method is running... even though they will interleave in CPython due to the GIL, but they will be executed concurrently. In other python implementations they might be executed in parallel.

Comment: @Bakuriu That answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not my answer, but @Bakuriu's, which is correct:

If the callback is passed to an other thread then, yes it can execute while your balance method is running... even though they will interleave in CPython due to the GIL, but they will be executed concurrently. In other Python implementations they might be executed in parallel.